# Can Knockout be made to observe ES6 symbols?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6, durandal-2.0

Using the new symbol type in **ES6** you can set non-iterable properties on objects. However when using **Knockout** these symbols are not observed by default.

It is possible to bind a symbol's value, but it is never updated as it isn't added to the observable object.

Has anyone been able to work around this problem and force **Knockout** to observe symbols?

Comment: In case you need symbols only to define non-enumerable properties: You can also set them via `defineProperty` with an `enumerable: false` descriptor.

Comment: Can you show the ES6 code, and how you're doing the binding?

Comment: Do you mean non-enumerable properties?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the observable plugin for Durandal is implemented similarly to the [Knockout-ES5](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5) plugin. When applied to a view model it's only going to create observables wrapped in a getter/setter for properties that are enumerable on the object.

[observable.defineProperty](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/observable/method/defineProperty) doesn't accept `enumerable` as a param but it does have `configuration: true`. This means that we can use `observable.defineProperty` (which will make the property enumerable) but then immediately make the property non-enumerable like so...

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'myProp', { enumerable: false });
```